# get null when i try to login,and submit button dont work Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

Hey i have a problem in login authetication.
I making a debug and find that my Database returns me null,but before it works.

So i dont know why its not work.
i try all stuff to find the bug,but dont find it.

I try to remove the auth. The problem is that the if i make console.log before validation it will work. and in  method login before the validation in if statement it will give me NULL

**DATABASE.SERVICE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../model/user';
import {serialize} from 
'@angular/compiler/src/i18n/serializers/xml_helper.d';

 @Injectable()
 export class DatabaseService {
 User: User;
  constructor() {
  this.User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  }
 login(email:string, password:string):boolean {
   //GIVE ME HERE UNDEFIEND
   if(email == 'admin' && password == 'admin'){
     this.User = {
      email:'admin',
      password:'admin'
   }
 }
  localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(this.User));
  return this.checkLogin();
 }
 logOut(): void{
  localStorage.clear();
 }
checkLogin():boolean{
 return (this.User != null);
 }
}
```

**LOGIN.COMPONENT**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {DatabaseService} from '../../service/database.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-login',
 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private database:DatabaseService,private router:Router) { }
 onFormSubmit(myForm:NgForm){
if(myForm.valid){
 //THE VALIDATION HERE IS WORKS
//THE STATEMENT DONT WORK.THE BUTTON DONT WORK.
  if(this.database.login(myForm.value['email'],myForm.value['password'])){   
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
   }
  }
 }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

 }
```

**HTML LOGIN**

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="onFormSubmit(myForm)" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
<button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**USER MODULE**

```
export class User{
email:string;
password:string;
};
```

Comment: please make it more clear, I do not understand what's your problem.

Comment: "Database returns me null,but before it works", What method returns you null, where? Before what it works? " if i make console.log before validation it will work", which validation, where? Comment your code, make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should return boolean from your login method

```
login(email:string, password:string):boolean {
   if(email == 'admin' && password == 'admin'){
       this.User = {
           email:'admin',
           password:'admin'
       };
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Your template is wrong, you do not use any of binding to model, take a look at https://angular.io/guide/forms or https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
Change your template to

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="onFormSubmit(myForm)" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="Enter email">
<input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
<button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and your component to

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {DatabaseService} from '../../service/database.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-login',
 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 email: string;
 password: string;

 constructor(private database:DatabaseService,private router:Router) { }
 onFormSubmit(myForm:NgForm){
if(myForm.valid){
 //THE VALIDATION HERE IS WORKS
//THE STATEMENT DONT WORK.THE BUTTON DONT WORK.
  if(this.database.login(this.email, this.password)){   
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
   }
  }
 }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

 }
```

Comment: it gives me the email get null,and ERROR CONTEXT

Comment: @alexandrlamdan you don't bind your data from template, please check this links